# Where can I find Cannondale bike's serial number if the sticker is missing?

Tags: cannondale, serial-number

I was looking at a used aluminum frame Cannondale from 2017 but the serial number sticker is missing:

> Cannondale bikes will display the serial number on the underside of the frame. It’ll be next to a bar code.
>
> [image: cannondale bike bottom bracket with serial number sticker highlighted]

Source: [Cannondale registration pgae](https://www.cannondale.com/en/bike-registration/register)

I was wondering if the serial number can be found somewhere else on the frame in case of a missing sticker. I have seen it stamped below the bottom bracket in other brands' aluminum frames, but not on this bike.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sometimes there's a number (though usually not the serial number) on one of the rear dropouts.

Comment: A missing serial number on a second hand frame could point towards a dubious provenance a.k.a theft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I heard back from Cannondale support. The sticker is the only way to know the serial number on their newer bikes:

> No, the serial number is not stamped on the frame. It is underneath the bottom bracket on a sticker with a bar code, 2 letters + 5 numbers.

Comment: Way to go Cannondale great way to help the bike thieves!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know my model or anything about my bike, but, I found some numbers imprinted into the metal on the bottom of the bike. The best way I can explain it is the number is where the back tire is, on the bottom of one of the horizontal rods, connected to the tire. (opposite of the gear side)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/57082)

Comment: That would be the "chainstay" on the non-drive side.     https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/4477#4477

Comment: Are you sure this is available on newer Cannondale bikes?